# Make Button Enabled after bools are true

Tags: c#, winforms

I need make Button active if theese three bools are true

```
public bool isFileOpened = false;
public bool isDrive = false;
public bool  isPrice = false;
```

They are becoming true after two textboxes are filled and 
filePath string is not empty

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    drive = CheckIntInput(sender, "not valid");
    if (drive != 0) {
        isDrive = true;
    }
}
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    price = CheckIntInput(sender, "not valid");
    if (price != 0) {
        isPrice = true;
    }
}
private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
    filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    label1.Text = filePath;
    isFileOpened = true;  
}
```

`CheckIntInput` method returning number from  textBox or 0 if can`t convert string to number

And how i can make something like this:

```
if (isFileOpened && isDrive && isPrice) {
    showButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

I want to make button enabled immediately after all three bools becomes true, and theese three fields can be inputted in different ways, like

1. textbox1
2. textbox2
3. openfiledialog1

or

1. textbox1
2. openfiledialog1
3. textbox2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, I'd use a property with a backing field, like this:

```
public bool IsFileOpened
{
    get { return _isFileOpened; }
    set
    {
        _isFileOpened = value;
        UpdateShowButton();
    }
}

public bool IsDrive
{
    get { return _isDrive; }
    set
    {
        _isDrive = value;
        UpdateShowButton();
    }
}

public bool IsPrice
{
    get { return _isPrice; }
    set
    {
        _isPrice = value;
        UpdateShowButton();
    }
}

private void UpdateShowButton()
{
    if (IsPrice && IsDrive && IsFileOpened)
        showButton.Enabled = true;
}
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    drive = CheckIntInput(sender, "not valid");
    if (drive != 0)
    {
        IsDrive = true;
    }
}
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    price = CheckIntInput(sender, "not valid");
    if (price != 0)
    {
        IsPrice = true;
    }
}
private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    label1.Text = filePath;
    IsFileOpened = true;
}
```

Actually I renamed it as well, so you have to use the properties with the capitalized starting letter. Now, everytime a property is updated, it checks wether to set the showButton enabled or not.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) you can read more about fields and properties (with backing fields as well).